# Várias páginas no mesmo arquivo HTML

Tags: html

**Olá pessoal**
É possível, apenas usando códigos HTML e Notepad++ por exemplo, embutir páginas distintas dentro de um  único arquivo HTML?

explico:
cria-se a estrutura da página inicial
no final dela insere-se um hiperlink 
**próxima página** e clicando nele segue 
para outra página no mesmo arquivo HTML

é possível? existe uma estrutura de comando que
permita isso com 1 página principal e 999 páginas " embutidas" 
via tag nessa primeira página interligada por hiperlinks

assim criando apenas um link HTML possível de vizualização Off-line

Clareando

o caso é esse, preciso achar uma forma de criar um HTML que tenha páginas "presas" não no formato corrido, mas em um só arquivo, um exemplo tosco se no Excel se eu crio um arquivo e coloco 10 planilhas, conecto uma planilha com a outra em usando hiperlink, depois salvo esse arquivo em formato HTML! Eureka! tenho um único arquivo HTML com 10 páginas "presas" conectadas via hiperlik ( em todas coloco um Hipelink página inicial) ( em todas coloco Prox. Pág e Pág Anterior) são 10 páginas separadas só visualizáveis via hiperlink em um só arquivo HTML. espero que tenha clareado minha pergunta. O Arquivo produto final será um só HTML. Obg-

Comment: Não entendi... são arquivos diferentes ou um único com uma rolagem gigante e você quer navegar pelas âncoras?

Comment: Mesmo que for possível, não é uma boa prática. Eu só consigo pensar em uma solução utilizando Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: Nem a GOOGLE faz isso meu amigo. Ele divida as página de resultados em links diferentes. Sua pergunta não está muito clara... Vc precisaria de 999 link, um para cada parte da página. Alem disso quando fizer a requisição vai ser como estivesse "carregando" 999 páginas de uma vez, ia ficar gigante... Sem querer ser grosseiro, mas não parece uma boa ideia. Talver com ajax ou php vc consigoa algo mais prático, com uma parte de paginação chamando os arquivos...

Comment: Ainda não ficou claro o que precisa.... melhor seria converter isso tudo em um PDF... vc precisa explicar melhor a dinâmica do que quer fazer como vai ser a paginação, o que vai ter de conteúdo na página, se pode ter barra de scroll ou "scroll infinito", etc

Comment: Se entendi bem, a forma mais próxima disso que eu imagino é usando somente CSS (https://output.jsbin.com/tatorapotu/1#page-1), mas isso demanda todas as páginas estarem no mesmo arquivo - de forma corrida -, mas que não atende seus requisitos.

Comment: Olá– Anderson Carlos Woss
de forma corrida poderia ser até no Word
mas não é o caso da necessidade - obg

Comment: Vc pode criar uma div principal e 999 divs ocultas, cada uma com o conteúdo que vc quer, como se fossem páginas diferentes. À medida que clica em "próxima página", vc puxa o conteúdo da div oculta para a div principal. Mas isso irá demandar uso de JavaScript.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título (sei que é uma prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui é desnecessário). Vc já aceitou uma resposta e isso é o suficiente.

Comment: Ha! ok, obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu pergunta está meio confusa, mas aqui tem uma opção.

Primeiro vc coloca `overflow:hidden` no `html` e `body`, depois vc cria várias section, cada uma vai ser uma página. O importante é que cada section tenha 100% da altura da tela e `overflow-y:auto`. Assim se o conteúdo da página tiver mais que 100% da altura da `section` o *scroll* aparece.

Os links de uma página para outra vc vai fazer na mão usando algo como `<a href="id-da-section">` `<section id="id-da-section">`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. Link no Codepen: https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/NomYqm

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="page-1">
  <h1>Página 1</h1>
  <a href="#page-2">Próxima</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et </p>



  <a href="#page-2">Próxima</a>
</section>

<section id="page-2">
  <h1>Página 2</h1>
  <a href="#page-1">Anterior</a>
  <a href="#page-3">Próxima</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
   </p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litoraauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>

  <a href="#page-1">Anterior</a>
  <a href="#page-3">Próxima</a>
</section>

<section id="page-3">
  <h1>Página 3</h1>
  <a href="#page-2">Anterior</a>
  <a href="#page-4">Próxima</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>

  <a href="#page-2">Anterior</a>
  <a href="#page-4">Próxima</a>
</section>

<section id="page-4">
  <h1>Página 4</h1>
  <a href="#page-3">Anterior</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor posuere neque, non elementum dui
    finibus eget. Suspendisse eget lorem ut orci ullamcorper laoreet. Nam suscipit at lacus et ullamcorper.
    Quisque ac risus eu arcu aliquet tempus quis sed sem. Aliquam dui est, cursus nec erat eu, posuere
    efficitur est. Aenean convallis vestibulum dolor, eu sodales arcu posuere a. Nullam euismod tempus turpis,
    vitae suscipit urna suscipit in. Nulla pellentesque massa id turpis pretium euismod.</p>

  <p>Praesent ultricies ligula at tortor euismod, sed mattis elit posuere. Integer aliquam elementum pretium. Sed
    a lorem pellentesque, consequat ipsum eget, elementum ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras semper neque nec ultricies rhoncus. Sed nec
    cursus sapien. Mauris in pretium leo. Aenean semper ultricies dictum. Aenean imperdiet mauris at magna
    tincidunt rhoncus. Morbi orci metus, interdum nec bibendum quis, dignissim a ex.</p>

  <a href="#page-3">Anterior</a>
</section>
```

Comment: quando copio e colo o código cria uma pagina apenas , mas corrida como se tivesse feito no WORD,  o que faltou fazer pra ficar como na GIF ?

Comment: Vc tem que coloca seu código, sem a tag Body, dentro da Section, depois vc tem que ir fazendo os links na tag A para pular de uma section para a outra

Comment: caro hugocsl, é possível trocar uma idéia via skype, whatsapp, face?

Comment: @petroniopetrarca essa hora eu to saindo aqui da empresa, e só consigo mexer mesmo com isso amanha. Mas pra facilitar pq vc não copia o código inteiro ai da pergunta para uma página HTML em branco e vai aos poucos colocando o seu material e fazendo os links, como vc pode ver não usei quase nada de CSS, não tem mistério esse código. Se preferir ele tb está postado nesse link do Codepen https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/NomYqm se for tendo dúvidas é só comentar ai, só não sei se consigo mexer mais com código hj, pois estou saindo aqui.

Comment: se não conseguir te falo amanhã , vlw, bom descando !

Comment: Prezado hugocsl, b . d . , não funciona mesmo,  é possível trocar uma idéia via skype, whatsapp, face?

Answer (score -3):

A forma mais pratica é utilizar um dos conceitos: div, frame, iframe ou frameset.

Obs: Uso de frames é considerado má prática em alguns usos.